# Show tooltip when hover on part of div by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to show tooltip when hover on some of div using JavaScript. The top left quarter of div.

Comment: Please add some code of what you're trying to do. There are 10s if not 100s of ways prebuilt online that do the same thing you asked

Comment: Try using bootstrap or material design ! It  can really hepl you in this topic

Comment: I am using jQuery

Comment: I need any example with jQuery

Comment: Just check out this pure CSS tooltip guide on W3Schools: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_tooltip.asp

Answer (score 0):

you can use freamwork javascript ([bootstrap](http://%20https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/tooltips/)) or [css](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_tooltip.asp) or [jQuery](https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/)

you can use this code :

```js
    function showTooltip(_obj){
    if(_obj.querySelector('#tooltip')!=null)
    return false;
    let tooltip=document.createElement('div');
    tooltip.innerText=_obj.getAttribute('title-js');
    tooltip.style.backgroundColor='black';
    tooltip.style.color='white';
    tooltip.id='tooltip';
    tooltip.style.position='absolute';
    tooltip.style.left=(_obj.offsetLeft-_obj.offsetWidth)+'px';
    tooltip.style.top=(_obj.offsetTop-_obj.offsetHeight)+'px';
    _obj.appendChild(tooltip);
    }

    function removeTooltip(_obj){
    if(_obj.querySelector('#tooltip')!=null)
    _obj.querySelector('#tooltip').remove();
    }
```

```css
 .hover-js{
    display:inline;
      color:red;
    }
```

```html
    <div>hello</div><br>
    <div>this is a test of <div class="hover-js" title-js="Hello" onmouseenter="showTooltip(this);" onmouseout="removeTooltip(this);">hover</div> from js.</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but I mean part of div

Comment: I need something like this but when hover on top left 2 px square http://jsfiddle.net/58Qdw/3/

Comment: The answer has been updated, please check.